# Устройство для отладки Android приложений

Tags: android

Собираюсь начать разрабатывать под Android. Соответственно, нужно устройство для тестов.
Пока мне приглянулись следующие 2-а варианта [android-2-1-tablet](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/7-touch-screen-tft-lcd-google-android-2-1-tablet-pc-w-wifi-camera-hdmi-telechips-8902-720mhz-44673) и [Orange San Francisco](https://eshop.orange.md/product.aspx?c=8&sc=89&l=2&i=361).

Какой, по мнению сообщества, из этих вариантов оптимальный или предложите другой, стоимостью до 250$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше Orange, потому как он больше приближен к реальной ситуации, я думаю ты в основном будешь разрабатывать софт под телефоны, а не китайские таблетки. Тем более Оранж очень хороший телефон, как сам по себе, вот обзор: [Orange San Francisco](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android/115492/).

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Обзор читал, его характеристики не сильно уступают планшету, так что с точки зрения железа они довольно таки похожи.

Comment: Да, только на планшете резистивный экран. И без поддержки мультитача.

Answer (score 2):

Хочу вставить свои пять копеек. Как уже писалось, для обучения действительно не нужен телефон в железе. Для разработки телефон нужен, всякие там сенсоры, смс-уведомления не все приходят, графика подтормаживает и т.д. Но за 250$ это будет не очень хороший андроид, мягко говоря :) Я для развлечения пишу сетевую игрушку, так у меня два телефона с разными прошивками, один 600$, другой 800. И еще совет: для эмулятора пишите на линуксе, у меня ноутбуку четыре года, на нем убунта, core 2 duo 2.4Ghz, 3GB DDR2 и вполне неплохо работает. Хотя может это мои тараканы, для меня вещи должны быть либо бесплатные, либо недешевые.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала разработки под Android вполне хватает эмулятора. Устройство есть смысл покупать, если только вы планируете отлаживать такие вещи, которые на эмуляторе не отлаживаются, а их не очень-то и много. Если у вас достаточно сильный рабочий компьютер, то эмулятор не будет заметно тормозить, и на нем можно продуктивно тестироваться.

Comment: Core 2 Duo E8500 3.8Mhz, 8Gb DDR2, GeForce Gtx 260.
Эмулятор безбожно тормозит, отлаживать можно разве что хелловорд и прочие простенькие приложения. Игры нереально, более менее нормальные приложения с работой с графикой или анимацией тоже бесполезно. Так что прогать на Андроид без девайса можно, но не долго.

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение, мне проще будет купить девайс, чем менять свою ноутбук.

Comment: С эмулятором действительно разрабатывать хреново и не удобно.

Answer (score 0):

Для разработки под андроид думаю необязательно покупать телефон, есть специальный эмулятор 
анроид телефона. А так, сам недавно выбирал себе телефон на андроиде, думаю лучше сони эриксон x8 за эти деньги, а у оранджа по-моему резистивный экран (еслиж нет, то по характеристика он вроде даже ничего так=))... От самсунгов <12000 лучше тоже отказаться, смотрел их непонтравились, уж очень тормознутые...
Я же решеил добавить немного денег и преобрести htc desire, о сделаном выборе нисколько не желею! И Вам советую взять сразу нормальный телефон ;)

Answer (score 0):

Пользуясь эмулятором, можно никогда и не узнать о реальных проблемах.
Советую htc desire hd. Отличный телефон. Запуск и отладка в разы быстрее чем на эмуляторе.